# PostgreSQL make CPU Usage 100%?

Tags: c#, wpf, cpu-usage, postgresql-9.3

I'm using `PostgreSQL` in my `WPF Application`.

Sometime the `PostgreSQL` makes CPU Usage up-to 100%.

I have encountered this issue many time, but I don't know the reason.

The snapshot image in Task Manager is below

[image]

Note that, When this bug occurs, I kill my application exe, and wait for during 5 minutes after that, but the status in task manager still not change. CPU still 100%

I see that, it usually happens after Window Update. And I must restart the computer to by pass this.

I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.3`.

Anyone can show me the way to fix this.

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you running a query when this happens?

Comment: Yes, my app is running query frequently, so i think that at this time is not an exception.

Answer (score 6):

If you are able to still access postgres, one thing I'd look at is do you have any queries that might be hung up

```
SELECT
  pid,
  now() - pg_stat_activity.xact_start AS duration,
  query,
  state
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '4 minutes';
```

if there is indeed a query that has been alive longer than it should be, you
can delete like so:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(<pid>);
```

This might not be the problem, but it will at least reduce the number of possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, I wil try and will let you know the result :)

Answer (score 1):

most the time the problem appears if you do not use indexing in the database, use indexing for fields that are used frequently especially if you use "order by" or aggregation (such as sum and count)